# Magento v1.7 - Why new contact form is redirected to default contact form after clicking submit button

Tags: magento

I created a new contact form (i.e. new-contact-form.phtml) and put the following code in CMS->Pages

```
{{block type='core/template' template='contacts/new-contact-form.phtml' form_action="/contacts/index/post"}}
```

However, the new contact form is redirected to default contact form after clicking submit button.

Can anyone help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

this what your form_action states this form is posted to `/contacts/index/post` controller and is redirected to a place that the controller has set

Comment: how can I make the page staying on the new contact form after submitting?

Comment: by exploring where the controller redirects and finding out if this is written in code or accessible through some parameter that you can pass on

Answer (score 0):

You could get the form action to redirect back to your cms page using a Custom URL redirect. For example, try entering a new Custom URL redirect with ID path and Request path both set to `contacts/index` and Target path set to the URL key of your CMS page, e.g. `contact-us`.